# CloudSearch javaScript API help to configure fq and query

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

I know I am doing wrong somewhere in setting parameters. Basically, I want to convert the below link to script.

[Click here to check the query](http://search-vegme-user-7l3rylms73566frh4hwxblekn4.us-east-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/search?q=nikhil&expr.distance=haversin(35.621966,-120.686706,latlong.latitude,latlong.longitude)&sort=distance%20asc&return=distance,displayname,profileimageurl)

```
aws.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-1'
});

AWS.config.apiVersions = {
  cloudsearchdomain: '2013-01-01',
  // other service API versions
};
var csd = new AWS.CloudSearchDomain({
  endpoint: 'search-vegme-user-7l3rylms73566frh4hwxblekn4.us-east-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com'
});
var params = {
  query: 'nikhil',
  /* required */
  expr: 'distance=haversin(35.621966,-120.686706,latlong.latitude,latlong.longitude)&sort=distance%20asc&return=distance,displayname,profileimageurl',
  filterQuery: 'latlong:['
  44.37094377949903,
  -78.40296337445523 ','
  42.92362822050097,
  -80.40316462554478 ']',
  partial: true,
  queryOptions: 'STRING_VALUE',
  queryParser: 'simple,
  return :'distance,id,fname',
  sort: 'asc',
};

csd.search(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  } else {
    console.log(data); // successful response
  }
});
```

Comment: Instead of using this soln to calculate the NearBy locations.I am using    2013-01-01/search?q=nikhil&expr.distance=haversin(35.621966,-120.686706,latlong.latitude,latlong.longitude)&sort=distance%20asc&return=distance,displayname,profileimageurl

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the above method to get the nearby locations

I am using 
the below link with HTTP module in my nodeJS

http://search-vegme-user-7l3rylms73566frh4hwxblekn4.us-east-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/search?q=nikhil&expr.distance=haversin(35.621966,-120.686706,latlong.latitude,latlong.longitude)&sort=distance%20asc&return=distance,displayname,profileimageurl

It will return all the top near locations for a given point

latlong is the valiable of type latlon

Answer (score 0):

You need to add params something like this

```js
var params = {
  'q': queryString,
  'cursor': "initial",
  'size': 5,
  'expr.distance': "(haversin(35.621966,-120.686706,latlong.latitude,latlong.longitude))",
  'sort': "distance asc",
  'q.parser': "structured",
  'return': "dietsinceyear,fbprofileid,reasonforveg,verified,since,displayname,locale,link,tagline,email,followingcount,agerangemin,shortdescription,vegstory,lastupdated,timezone,diet,followercount,fbupdated_time,coverimageurl,lname,id,gender,profileimageurl,categoryids,fname,distance"
}
```